# Why ORA-06576 appears when the procedure is being called?

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, compiler-errors

I have to create a procedure that inserts a line item (product code) and quantity for a specific invoice. The procedure can only take 4 parameters – invoice x, line item y, product code z and quantity w.

```
create or replace procedure line_item(x in number,
                                      y in number,
                                      z in VARCHAR2,
                                      w in number)
as
begin

  insert into lab9_line (inv_number, line_number, p_code,
                         line_units, line_price, line_total) 
  values(x, y, z, w, 0, 0);

end;
/
```

When I call the function:

```
call procedure LINE_ITEM(6666,1,0666-SA,6,6.66,6.66);
```

I get the error:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-06576: not a valid function or procedure name
06576. 00000 -  "not a valid function or procedure name"
*Cause:    Could not find a function (if an INTO clause was present) or
           a procedure (if the statement did not have an INTO clause) to
           call.
*Action:   Change the statement to invoke a function or procedure
```

Comment: ORA-06576 means that you are using Oracle, please don't add tags for irrelevant RDBMSs such as SQL Server and MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

The correct application of the `EXEC` syntax is the following:

```
EXEC LINE_ITEM(6666,1,'0666-SA',6,6.66,6.66);
```

Or using an anonymous PL/SQL block:

```
BEGIN
    LINE_ITEM(6666,1,'0666-SA',6,6.66,6.66);
END;
/
```

Note that you're also passing too many arguments to the procedure...

Comment: Also, I'd advise using implicitly given parameters while executing the procedure (`EXEC LINE_ITEM(x => 6666,y => 1, z => '0666-SA', w => 6);`). Then it's way easier to mantain the parameters' quantity :)